# Extending the "Files" menu

Tags: acumatica

I have a process that involves extending the "Files" menu that is located on (most) acumatica pages (next to notes and activities in the top right)

I would like to add two columns to the table that appears in the smartpanel.

I have been looking for the source code/data behind this smart panel and I cant seem to find it, is it tied into SM202520 (search in files)? Can it be extended?

Am I better off just adding a PXAction button to the 3 or 4 pages I want my extended "files" menu to be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `DataView` bound to that dialog, you can verify that by using inspect element shortcut key CTL+ALT+CLICK on a grid column header:
[image]

In order to be customized the grid needs to be bound to a `DataView` which inspect element reveals it is not. The lack of `DataView` binding is by design and therefore that dialog can't be customized.

A grid that can be customized will show the `View Name` property:
[image]

Comment: As I suspected, thanks! Ill see if I can accomplish the overall objective by directly modifying the "search in files" screen instead

Comment: The customization project editor doesn't list the graph of that screen UploadFileInq as available for extending. There's also some little glitches occurring when customizing the screen. But overall while it's likely discouraged it appears to be possible to modify that screen just like any other and if using customization project editor you can create the graph extension manually using new code file option instead of choosing graph extension option in new code file dialog. I was successful in adding Comment field to the files grid and having the graph extension picked up by the system.